# Hashtable in F#

Tags: f#, hashmap, hashtable

Is there an alternative to [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`System.Collections.Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.add.aspx)?

I'm unhappy with the former because it returns value using `byref`, i.e., I need to do the annoying

```
let x = ref ""
if hashtable.TryGetValue (key, x) then
    // Found, value in !x
else
    // Not found.
```

I'm unhappy with the latter because it's not generic.

EDIT. I'd prefer something generic syntactically looking like `Map.tryFind`, i.e.,

```
match Hashtable.tryFind k hashtable with
| None -> ...    // Not found
| Some v -> ...  // Found v.
```

Comment: How *do* you want to get a value for a possibly missing key?  What method signature would you *want* to see?  Once you know that, create an extension method using that signature that uses this method, or whatever other methods are appropriate, as it's implementation.

Comment: In F# the best one would probably be `Some<TKey>`

Comment: @Servy I expect, like in Map and as suggested by MarcinJuraszek, to have `tryFind : 'k -> Hashtable<'k,'v> -> Option<'v>`. I was also expected to find that made for me someplace already. The reason it's not seems tobe in @Daniel's answer.

Comment: @SørenDebois Then say that in your question.  You've described something that you don't like, but you need to also described what you *do* want to see for someone to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Out parameters are part of living with the .NET framework. F# does minimize the pain, however, by automatically tuplizing them along with the return value. So, using `Dictionary<_,_>` you can do:

```
match d.TryGetValue(key) with
| true, x -> ... //tuple of return value and out parameter
| _ -> ...
```

See [*Passing by Reference* on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx).

You could easily wrap that into an extension:

```
type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<'K, 'V> with
  member x.TryFind(key) =
    match x.TryGetValue(key) with
    | true, v -> Some v
    | _ -> None
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two collection types in F# you should look at:

> [`Collections.Set<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353619.aspx) Class (F#)
>
> Immutable sets based on binary trees, where comparison is the F#
>   structural comparison function, potentially using implementations of
>   the IComparable interface on key values.

> [`Collections.Map<'Key,'Value>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353686.aspx) Class (F#)
>
> Immutable maps. Keys are ordered by F# generic comparison.

`Map` has a function you're looking for:

> `Map.TryFind`
>
> Lookup an element in the map, returning a `Some` value if the element
>   is in the domain of the map and `None` if not.

Comment: But I didn't want immutable and O(lg n) lookups! I specifically asked for a hashtable?